# ArcGIS query - how can I find the average value (water consumption) from set of polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, choropleth

I am fairly new to arcgis, so this is probably a really simple task, but I would like to ask advice so I can learn how to do it. :)

Basically,

I have a polygon layer that has attributes for each house within a set of neighborhoods each house has the attribute of which neighborhood that it belongs to as well as its water consumption.

My problem is this, I want to be able to find the average water consumption for each neighborhood by averaging the water consumption of each house within that neighborhood, and then be able to show average water consumption for each neighborhood on a choropleth map.

Could anyone give me advice on what is the best way to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'd try `Summary Statistics` from the `Analysis` toolbox. Set the neighbourhood attribute as the case field and the water consumption attribute as the statistics field with `MEAN` aggregation mode (or another appropriate one). This way, you get a data table.

If you have a polygon layer covering the entire area (without gaps), you can just use `Dissolve` to obtain a polygon layer of neighbourhoods to which you can `Join` the data table created before.

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you very much for your response - so when I do the first step, am I right in thinking this will create an additional column in the attribute table with the mean water consumption in it?

Comment: No. `Summary Statistics` will create a new table (not a feature class, just an attribute table with no spatial data). But it will contain a neighbourhood identifier you specified in the case field, which you can use to join the contained mean water consumption data to the polygon feature class created by `Dissolve`.